# Fast mp4 to mp3 converter

Tags: audio, media-converter

I have to convert an audio file in mp4 format into mp3 format. With [Free Audio Converter](http://www.freemake.com/free_audio_converter/) it takes approximately two minutes for 10 MB. I need to convert larger files (e.g. 70 MB).

The quality of the mp4-to-mp3 conversion for my purpose is secondary. What counts is only the total time needed for conversion.

What is a fast mp4 to mp3 freeware converter?

Comment: Can also try with this [MP4 To MP3 Converter](http://download.cnet.com/MP4-To-MP3-Converter/3000-2140_4-75670619.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) (open source, Windows / Linux / Mac OS X). [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/332347/how-can-i-convert-mp4-video-to-mp3-audio-with-ffmpeg/332348#332348) from Super User provides two commands that should work:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 filename.mp3
```

Comment: While *FFmpeg* might fit the OP's needs, your answer lacks some details (see [our quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185)). Especially it doesn't address the core requirement: is it a ***fast*** encoder? Also missing: what makes it recommendable (preferably personal experience). Could you please [edit] your answer to improve it, filling the gaps? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is *the* media converter. If you don't want to use a command line to access it, use the [FFE](http://corz.org/windows/software/ffe/) frontend if you're on Windows.

FFE uses your existing installation of FFmpeg (which must be [added to your PATH](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows)) and executes the command line instructions for you. It's not as powerful for doing very advanced things, but it allows you to do almost anything a normal file conversion would require.

I use it with the *Open With* dialogue in the context menu for my media files to quickly open that file. Then I just change the file extension in the second field, *Output*, and hit *Do It!* to convert the file.

The nice thing about this solution is that it's entirely free, FFmpeg is very powerful, and FFE is a great way to use the freedom and power of FFmpeg without having to memorize and type out long command line inputs.

[image: FFE screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You might also try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/): it has got a "convert" function and it's pretty easy to use.

One thing: you told us that two minutes for 10 MB are unacceptable, but you didn't tell us the specifications of the machine the converter has to run on.

Comment: While *FFmpeg* might fit the OP's needs, your answer lacks some details (see [our quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185)). Especially it doesn't address the core requirement: is it a ***fast*** encoder ("pretty easy" was no criterium given ;)? Also missing: what makes it recommendable (preferably personal experience). Could you please [edit] your answer to improve it, filling the gaps? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Free video converter will fit in your scenario, as it’s absolutely free (both for windows and Mac).  Besides essential conversion ability, it also provides in-program editing functions like trimming, cropping, rotating, merging, adding subtitles and watermarks, etc. to enrich your digital enjoyment.

http://www.wondershare.com/mp4/free-mp4-to-mp3-converter.html

Some additional Features:

- Convert to various audio formats, MP3, AC3, AAC, AC3, WMA, etc.
- Work at 30X faster speed than any conventional converter.
- Convert to different devices to play, like Apple, Samsung, etc. (Pro
  Version).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Format Factory](http://www.pcfreetime.com/). It can convert between many filetypes such as audio, video, photos, and more and it is super quick. It is also completely free. The only thing is that you have to be sure to skip the bundleware during install but after that it's great and has no better options in my opinion. It's also super quick even at large batch jobs!